Was there ever a MacBook Pro 2020 with intel Processor and without Touch Bar?
I found an offer online for a MacBook Pro 2020 with Intel i7 processor and without Touch Bar (that is, with physical Esc and F1-F12 keys). Did such a model ever exist? I have not heard about anything like it. I thought the Touch Bar was first removed with the M1 MacBooks.

Might be a MacBook Air. The 2020 (and earlier) 13" MBA has no Touch Bar. The 2020 MBA can have an i7 processor.

Wouldn't an Air be hard to pass off as a Pro due to the different body shape?  Could it be a Pro from 2010–2016 (all of which can have i7)?

@gidds Could be that too.  Clearly someone is trying to pass off something.

It could be that Apple was still selling an earlier model in 2020, and that's just when they bought it.

According to everymac.com, all 2020 Intel MacBook Pro models have a Touch Bar. This is true even for the 2019 Intel MacBook Pro models introduced in 2020.
